# A Null Exception When Adding to a List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

**The Model:**

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; } = "400";
    public List<string> Message { get; set; }
}
```

I initialized the model here. When it goes to add the string to it there is always a null exception/reference error. I'm completely doing this wrong?

```
 ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();

 errorMessage.Message.Add("The transaction could not be processed");
```

Comment: Is the list initialized?

Comment: Fun fact, just because you made a new `ErrorMessage`, doesn't mean that `Message` is initialized.

Comment: `public List<string> Message { get; set; } = new();` or `public List<string> Message { get; set; } = new List<string>();` you need to initialize this property before trying to do anything related with it.

Comment: @zaggler Even better, `public List<string> Message { get; private set; } = new();`. No one outside the type needs set access to the property. Even if you want to add or remove items, that's still a `get` operation.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I agree with you, thanks for the feedback!